# What is the best way to load child sql to make a tree?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

What is the best way to load data from sql server to make something like a tree in java.

I have

```
+----+--------+-------+
| ID | Parent | Title |
+----+--------+-------+
| 1  | NULL   | First |
| 2  | 1      | AAAAA |
| 3  | 1      | BBBBB |
| 4  | 2      | CCCCC |
+----+--------+-------+
```

I want to load objects like (object with id 1).getChild().getChild().getTitle() returning CCCCC

Do I have to loop through sql results and load again the child? Or have a best way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to create a view in MySQL that can returns a table of your original table joined to itself on Parent=ID, which the corresponding ID as a new child column. 
You can call a view like this as many times as needed to traverse down the child links and get the title

For the example you gave :

```
Given the view
   Children
+----+-------+
| ID | CHILD |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 2     |
| 1  | 3     |
| 2  | 4     |
+----+-------+

Select OT.Title
From OriginalTable AS OT
     INNER JOIN Children AS CID on OT.ID = CID.ID
     INNER JOIN Children AS C1 on CID.CHILD = C1.ID
     INNER JOIN Children AS C2 on C2.CHILD = C2.ID
WHERE OT.ID = 1
```

This will return ALL titles which are the children of children of element with ID 1.

You can abstract this out to a stored procedure that takes an ID as a parameter, or repeat the inner join to reach the Nth children.

Comment: if i had 10 children i have to make 10 inner join?

Comment: If one node has 10 children, you only need 1 inner join.
However, if you mean that you want to traverse down 10 levels of children, then yes, you would need that many inner joins.